# Make cursor point to the end of the text in input box instead of at the beginning using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to implement a behavior where when selection is made by the user from the options list, after filling the the input box with the selected text the cursor pointer stays at the end of the text entered. The only constrain I have is I am unable to pass event object. So I cannot use event.currentTarget.value.length or something similar. I only have the option to call document.getElementByID or any of the other properties. But the text value that will be filled has dynamic classNames. Currently, I use Id name of the input box but that causes the cursor pointer to focus at the beginning of the text.
[image]

The code that I have used is:

```
document.getElementById('tags-container').focus();
```

The DOM structure of the input text is as follows:
[image]

Ideally I should use tc-tag-1 id so that the focus is after the text but that id is dynamically created. As I keep adding more selection, the tc-tag number keeps increasing. So I want to keep the cursor pointer at the last text entered. Is there any other attribute that I can use ? Is there any other way I can do without using event object.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to implement it in your input box with `div` element. But I will give an example of a set cursor at the end of the text with `input` element using `setSelectionRage`. ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange))

```js
document.getElementById('tags-container').onfocus = function(e) {
  let element = e.target;
  let targetCursor = element.value.length;
  setTimeout(function(){
    element.setSelectionRange(targetCursor, targetCursor);
  }, 1);
}
```

```html
<input id="tags-container" type="text" />
```

Comment: I am unable to add function to document.getElementById. I get Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression error

Comment: please show screen capture of the error

Comment: I cannot paste screen capture in the comment section.

Comment: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression. (324:6)

  322 |       });
  323 |
> 324 |       document.getElementById('tags-container').focus() = putCursorInEnd();
      |       ^

Comment: Just use `.onfocus = function(e) {` instead of `.focus() = putCursorInEnd()`

Comment: Same thing with onfocus too!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Selection.modify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/modify)

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('input').focus()
  window.getSelection().modify('move', 'right', 'paragraph')
})
```

```html
<input value="Lorem"/>
<button>Put cursor at the end</button>
```